# How to include large JSON file in frontend using Js/React/Gulp/Webpack-combo

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, gulp, webpack

for a project I need to include a large JSON file in my web frontend for data visualization. The JOSN file is 9MB large.

How can I include it. My stack is JavaScript, Node.js, React, Gulp, Webpack.

I tried to just include it via import in my React module:

```
import data from '../assets/data.json';
```

However when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
[09:50:32] Error: Command failed: cd web && gulp --max-old-space-size=4096 build
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
```

I tried using this `--max-old-space-size=4096` that you find as general solution for this problem on SO but I did not help.

So my question is:

How can I include this large JSON file in my frontend?
Sure I could load it deferred after the page has been loaded directly from the server but I would like to include it directly in the page. Loading times are irrelevant in this case. The frontend will not be hosted somewhere publicly. So what are my options to include this using React/Webpack/gulp and how do I do it? Can I somehow include that file without being parsed by webpack which causes this out-of-memory-error?

Comment: you should use a database which you can query data from it, because 9MB js script loading makes page very slow.

Comment: Loading times do not matter. The page will be loaded maybe once a day. Also gzipped the 9MB are just like 600kb.

Comment: Try this workaround `node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build` (if gulp is installed locally) because `max-old-space-size` is not an argument for gulp, but node

Comment: @Freez: .bin/gulp is a shell script and cannot be executed by node. I had to do `node --max-old-space-size=2000 ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js build`. But this has the same memory error.

Comment: Actually I got it to work with 8GB memory limit. But compiling with webpack takes nearly 3min. WTF does webpack do??? I used the json-loader for json files, which basically just parses the json and writes it out again. That should not take this long? Is there some other possibility to include the JSON file in the page bypassing React/JavaScript includes? Maybe just put it unparsed into the static files directory and have it included in the html-file? How would I do this with Gulp/Webpack?

Comment: You could try ``IgnorePlugin`` for Webpack: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/ eg. ``new webpack.IgnorePlugin("myLargeDatafile")``